# NSUserDefaults vs CoreData for storing data

Tags: swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I am coding an App that requires a friends list to manage. I am pulling all of the users friends from Firebase and then storing them into a dictionary.

```
let friends: [String : Friend] = [String: Friend]()
```

As so. Where "Friend" is an object of itself.

I am then storing them/archiving them into NSUserDefaults to be used in other areas of the app so only 1 query is being made to firebase at a time unless forced to refresh.

Is it wise to store this "large data" into nsuserdefaults and thus calling them in other view controllers of the app or should I use another method to store them within the app?

Comment: If you have a large list then CoreData will be a better choice unless you will need to handle pruning of the objects from `NSUserDefaults` which is most of the time makes code buggy.

Comment: This is the wrong use of `UserDefaults`.

Comment: @Rahul I see okay. I will look more into CoreData thanks!